# how to get missing elements from array of Object? suppose my array of object is coming from server as Follow

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

```
data:[{time :9:15},    {time :9:16},    {time :9:17},    {time :9:18},        {time :9:19}, {time :10:15},  {time :10:16},  {time :10:17}, {time :10:18} ]
```

this array I am getting from the server and am printing it in the table on the screen . But if you can see this data is not in continues form. If data is not in an array I want to show that data and show it on screen. Suppose data is not present after 9:19  is not present then my o/p should be 9:15 9:16.....9:19 9:20 9:21 9:22 ...10:14.

Comment: What do you want to show when the data is not in array ?

Comment: you mean have a array like this `[{time:"9:00"},{time:"9:01"},{time:"10:00"}]`, and you want create `objects` between `9:01` and `10:00` which are missing; right?

Comment: yes using moment js and angular js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data=[{time :'9:15'}, {time :'9:16'}, {time :'9:17'}, {time :'9:18'}, {time :'9:19'}, {time :'10:15'}, {time :'10:16'}, {time :'10:17'}, {time :'10:18'}];

var h = th = +data[0].time.split(':')[0]; 
var m = tm = data[0].time.split(':')[1] - 1;
var h2 = +data[data.length - 1].time.split(':')[0]; 
var m2 = +data[data.length - 1].time.split(':')[1];

var result = [];
do {    
    if(h2 == th && m2 == tm)
 break;
    tm++;
    if(tm == 60){
 tm=0;
 th++;
    }
    result.push({time: th+':'+tm});
}while(true);

console.log(result);
```